# How to use parameters in Google Analytics API

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

How to use parameters in `getResults` function? I need to get information about what urls of my website users are watching. In case when i use `ga:sessions`, I see how many users was there. If I change it to `ga:pageviews` the number (in result array) is changes. So it means that API is "alive".

How do I get URLs "points of enter" where people starting to watch my website. And how to send parameters in this place `'ga:sessions');` ?
API instructions I was reading are [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php#helloanalyticsphp).

```
function getResults(&$analytics, $profileId) {
  // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
  // for the last seven days.
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,

       '7daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:sessions');
}

function printResults(&$results) {
  // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
  // the profile name and total sessions.
  if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

    // Get the profile name.
    $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

    // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
    $rows = $results->getRows();
//    $sessions = $rows[0][0];

    // Print the results.

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($rows);


  } else {
    print "No results found.\n";
  }
}
```

For now result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3585
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your request

```
$analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profileId,    
                         '7daysAgo',
                         'today',
                         'ga:sessions');
```

What you are doing is asking Google Analytics to give you the number of sessions for your profile between today and 7 days ago.   Which it is infact doing.  There have been 3585 sessions during that time frame

Now if you check the [dimensions and metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) you will find a large list of dimensions and metrics.    ga:sessions is a metric ga:pageviews is a dimension so you need to add the dimension to your request.

```
$params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:pageviews');    
$analytics->data_ga->get('ga:' . $profileId,    
                         '7daysAgo',
                         'today',
                         'ga:sessions',
                         $params);
```

Now run your request and you should get a list of each page with the total number of sessions for that page.

Tip:

```
foreach ($results->getRows() as $row) {         
    print $row[0]." - ".$row[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! And how to show result page after page? Cuz default max result is 1k

Comment: I don't have code for that sorry.   But I "think" you read the nextpage token on the results from your request then pass it to a new request as a params like you did with dimensions just add a new one  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/pagination  Sorry its been a while since I have done it.